# Using Calendar object in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, calendar, derby

I'm using Netbeans and Derby database. I would like to insert to a table records with date field, so I was told to use `Calendar` object since it contains what I need:  date (day, month and year), hour and minute.

As you can see in the code below, the table field is of type `DATE`.
When I try to insert the `Calendar` object as a String (with commas like in the code below), I get:

> The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect.

When I try to insert it without commas I get:

> Syntax error: Encountered "[" at line 1, column 159

Probably something with the Calendar object. What am I missing here?

```
String from = fromForm.getText();
String to = toForm.getText();
String []date = dateForm.getText().split("/");
String []time = timeForm.getText().split(":");
int places = Integer.parseInt(placesForm.getText());
int closinghours=Integer.parseInt(closingHoursForm.getText());
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(Integer.parseInt(date[2]),Integer.parseInt(date[1]),Integer.parseInt(date[0]),Integer.parseInt(time[0]),Integer.parseInt(time[1]));

String query="INSERT INTO APP.TRUMPS (TRUMPID,DEPART,ARRIVE,START,PLACES,PROPOSING_USER_LOGIN,CLOSING_HOURS)"+
        "VALUES ('"+newTrampTrumpistClient.login+dateForm.getText()+timeForm.getText()+"','"+from+"','"+to+
                "','"+calendar+"',"+places+",'"+newTrampTrumpistClient.login+"',"+closinghours+")";
String result=newTrampTrumpistClient.WritingReading("sql_insert", query);
```

Comment: You should avoid to compose yourself the query string in that way. There are a lot of i18n and l10n issues involved in the way a DB receives a date string, generally highly configurable. Try using JDBC PreparedStatement with setParameter() method to set the values for your query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [`PreparedStatement#setTimestamp()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29) to set a `TIMESTAMP/DATETIME` field (or [`setDate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29) to set a `DATE` field, but that doesn't cover hours and minutes...).

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO"
    + " APP.TRUMPS (TRUMPID, DEPART, ARRIVE, START, PLACES, PROPOSING_USER_LOGIN, CLOSING_HOURS)"
    + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
// ...

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
// ...

try {
    // ...
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, newTrampTrumpistClient.login+dateForm.getText()+timeForm.getText());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, from);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, to);
    preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
    preparedStatement.setInt(5, places);
    preparedStatement.setString(6, newTrampTrumpistClient.login);
    preparedStatement.setInt(7, closinghours);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    // ...
} finally {
    // ...
}
```

Additional bonus is that using prepared statements protects your application from [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

#### See also:

- [JDBC tutorial - using prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, converting from `String` to `Calendar` is pretty clumsy. Consider using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert from `String` to `Date`. You can then persist it as `new Timestamp(date.getTime())`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a bit of extra info...

Have you thought of using a [Java.utils.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) object?

You can construct it with as much, or a little granularity as you desire, eg. from just the 'date' (year:month:day) all the way down to including millisecond time precision.

Then you can capture the parts you want with the various getXXX() methods.

You have to do a little bit of jiggery pokery by passing your date object into the calendar object (probably by way of a [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), follow a link there is a nice example on the java doc page).

Alternatively you can use your Java.util.Date and pass it to a Java.sql.date by way of the getTime() method of java.util.date.

You can do the same with the java.sql.time (ie, pass in the same object and you will end up with just the time portion of your java.util.date object). If you pass the same method to an sql.timestamp it will give the full timestamp.

You can also conver back from the timestamp, to either the date or time part using the same procedure (sql.timestamp - to- util.date -to- sql.date (or) sql.time), although most DB's allow casting from one to the other natively.

When you pass the getTime() method to your java.util.date object it returns a 'long' value (ie the time since the Unix epoch of 1st jan 1970 !) I don't know how it handles times and dates before this (I assume they are just a 'negative' value ?).

You can even store your date in your DB as a long value, if you want to confuse your cliens and obsfuscate your code ;)

David

Answer (score -1):

Try retrieving the time from the calendar instance. 
ie, calendar.getTime(). ( it returns Date object)
You may also need to cast it to sql date.

Comment: what was the downvote for? Explanation would be definitley helpful.

Comment: Fair enough, sorry for not explaining. (1) The question gave the need to have HH:MM:SS, so you need a sql timestamp column, not a sql date. (2) it's easy to get confused between java.sql.Date and java.util.Date; your answer leads the user toward that confusion, not away from it, (3) you can't cast j.u.Date to j.sql.Date (4) it's a bad habit to be trying to construct query statements as strings; parameter substitution is far superior, particularly with dates and times which have such odd string formats, and the other answer's suggestion to use PreparedStatement.setTimestamp is thus superior.

Comment: I apologise for misleading the user. However, (1) In line three of the question, he mentioned that the filed is Date, thats why I expected he needed the date object ( not timestamp however).(2) I gave him hints rather than the full solution, so I thought it would guide him rather than misleading as it would give him the idea of where he was wrong.  (3) you CAN cast java.util.Date to SQL date. (4)I think this is a place to provide logical/syntactical solution of the code, not a right place to review the code.(for judgement purpose specifically). codereview.stackexchange.com is for code review

Comment: Compile this and run it, and you'll get the casting failure: public class date
{
 public static void printdt( java.sql.Date sd )
 {
  System.out.println("sql date: " + sd );
 }
 public static void main( String []args)
 {
  printdt( (java.sql.Date)new java.util.Date() );
 }
}

Comment: +1 for the clarification. I was confused with the class hierarchy , thought j.u.Date extends sql.Date()